# How to import a corpus from nltk in a variable to form ngarms in python?

Tags: nlp, nltk, n-gram, reuters

I want to form an ngram using nltk corpus reuters. I tested my code to form ngrams on a small corpus saved on my local disk as a text file using:

```
import nltk
file = open('dummytext.txt', encoding = 'utf8').read()
```

Now that my ngram probability code makes sense to me. I want to use the nltk corpus reuters which is a huge corpus so when i do the following:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import reuters
file = reuters.words()
```

The processing to form unigrams goes on for eternity

How to unpack the nltk corpus as string in a variable to form ngrams using nltk?

Comment: Why do you think a text file that you'd have to split into words yourself is faster than a dedicated file for it.
Loading the words from `reuters` and counting them takes about `1.9` seconds on my machine, if your time is significantly off I expect your algorithm to be suboptimal or the problem you're trying to solve is just a hard one.
Anyways without some code we can't exactly help you figure out what's so slow.

Comment: I am very new to nlp and python as well so i dont know if this si the right way to do it.
This is what  i did:
import nltk 
from nltk.corpus import reuters
reuters_dataset=" ".join(reuters.words())
from nltk import word_tokenize
import re 
corpus=re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',"",reuters_dataset)
corpus_new=corpus.lower()
wor=nltk.word_tokenize(corpus_new)

words=wor[:30000] #Sliced the dataset for reducing processing complexity ()
I want to use the whole corpus not slice it. Let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: Please add the code as edit to the original question since in comments it gets horribly mangled.